# How to do SUM aggregate and put it in new column as grandtotal in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregate

This what my table look like:

```
id         amount         price
5          2              10
8          4              30
5          3              20
```

this is my desired result:

```
id         amount         price     subtotal     grandtotal
5          2              10          20            80
5          3              20          60
8          4              30         120            120
```

if we use sum and group by id, it will group two rows with id 5 into 1 row and just calculate the grand total, but i need to keep the detail of each row like above. (*it doesn't matter where to put the `80` can be in the first or second row as long as it's there.*)

Is that possible in MySQL ? or do i need to do it in PHP or other language ?

Thanks very much.

Kind Regards,
LL

Answer (score 0):

Not really efficient, but works :

```
select id, amount, price, amount*price subtotal, 
(select sum(amount*price) from table where id = t.id) grandTotal
from table t
```

Comment: how to fetch the `id = t.id` if it's coming from the same table ? Thanks

Comment: The query above works fine in case of the same tables. Just replace `table` with your table name and run it.